# What became of PoSSo and FRISCO

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra, symbolic-computation

I know PoSSo and FRISCO were pretty big projects involving many European universities.
Interestingly, I couldn't find much information about these projects
(the the top of the PoSSo homepage says "under construction",
and the bottom of the page says "Last update: december 1996").

I'm just curious:

- Is there any continuation project?
- To what extend did these projects advanced computational algebraic geometry?
- Within the community, were/are they considered a success?
- Outside the community, were/are they well known?
- Outside the community, were the resulting software packages considered useful?

Comment: The FRISCO project homepage http://www.nag.co.uk/projects/FRISCO.html has a "final project report" that may help.

Comment: @M T the link is broken, do you have any updates?